# Need information about the history of the Hotelling and Bodewig method

Tags: linear-algebra

I need information about Hotelling and Bodewig, who they were and why they developed this method. anything will help, references to articles, links, or any other information.

Link to the method: http://ads.harvard.edu/books/1990fnmd.book/chapt2.pdf page 41 (2.3.10)

Comment: Hi, welcome to hsm. Hotelling-Bodewig algorithm is an iterative method for finding matrix inverse. It might help to add some context, e.g. what you need the information for, and what specific aspects or applications you are interested in. Hotelling's 1933 paper is cited here http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3933421/ and his dispute with von Neumann over matrix inversion here (p.622) http://www.mathe.tu-freiberg.de/~ernst/Lehre/Grundkurs/Literatur/grcar2011.pdf

Comment: I need it for an article/project I need to write. the points in general: 

1.  the history of algorithm (who invented it? when?
AND what was the motivation to invent this algorithm).

2.  The technical mathematical
theoretical infrastructure for the theory (not proofs only the logical order of
things).